# Steps of a clustering problems composed by right-skewed data and large number of zeros

Tags: clustering, k-means, standardization, zero-inflation

I'm trying to cluster a dataset based on 190 diabetic patients and 20 columns (features of patients) and many of these features have most zeros (to understand better, the median of 8 of 20 features is 0), with non-normal distribution.
The steps I've followed are:

- extraction feature
- z-standardization of the variables
- application of PCA for dimensionality reduction
- execution of k-means
- results analysis

I'm not sure about the results.
I had to eliminate features that were too important according to the pca, but that in my case study are actually not so relevant (for example, in these features, due to standardization, the value of few non-zero values ​​is higher and hence there are features weighing more than others; this creates forced clusters, composed only of occurrences that dominate these features).

In my opinion, both z-standardization and K-means aren't correct approach for my final purpose but in literature I didn't find a solution.

What do you think are the correct phases in this specific problem?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think this is a decent question, but it is also very broad at present. What is it you are trying to do? What is the point of the cluster analysis? What will you do with the results? Also, what are your variables?

Comment: Please describe your features, what is their scale, units.

Comment: @gung The purpose is to find similarities between diabetic patients without having a priori knowledge of clusters that can be formed.
The features are age, gender (0 or 1), days between a purchase and the next of diabetic products (on average), number of packs purchased for diabetic therapy (4 types), number of packs purchased for a therapy concomitant with diabetic (e.g. cardiovascular, nervous system, metabolism).
The main problem is that many patients follow some therapy, but not of each type. For example, those who don't suffer from cardiovascular disease will have 0 purchased quantities

Comment: @ttnphns The features are described in the above answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the use of either z standardization, nor PCA, nor both (which always seems a bit redundant, and often does very odd transforms) on data with many 0s is a good idea. The zeros usually have some clear semantic, and these transformations will *destroy* such properties.

Don't approach this as a black box and just stack function calls. You need to find a statistical model that explains the data. Your transformation backwards, that is the generation process you assume. So you begin with k values, add low-variance iid Gaussian noise. Then scale and rotate the data, scale and translate again, etc.

Instead, you want a model like "with p the value is zero. With 1-p it is drawn from " and then argue about these differences being random by chance to get a similarity function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not very clear to me. In particular the part related to the search for a statistical model that allows me to explain the data, and the model explained. (An example regarding a feature I've written in the above comment may be clarifier). 
A question: if in my case neither standardization nor PCA are a good idea, do you think that clustering is not the best approach either?

Comment: I don't think the data will be easy to cluster; certainly not before you have found a way to model the data generation and similarity. I can't provide you a finsihed solution - I don't have your data. And I'm not saying this is easy. But your data is not easy, either.